# Is it possible to restrict google authentication to specific group of users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.1, omniauth-google-oauth2

I have recently used `omniauth-google-oauth2` gem in one of my rails 5 application for authenticating users, and it is working fine. The application is intended for specific group of users, in my case students of a university. All users have a google account with email addresses ending with `@ait.asia` or `@ait.ac.th`.

Is it possible to restrict authentication to only above mentioned users. i.e. only users with email addresses ending with `@ait.asia` or `@ait.ac.th`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a list of Google Apps hosted domains to the `hd` option when you are adding the OmniAuth middleware to your application.

So, in your case, you can make a initializer like this:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2,
    ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"],
    ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"],
    hd: %w(ait.asia ait.ac.th)
```

You can see a complete list of the configuration options [here](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/blob/master/README.md#configuration)